# How to stop nagios from initially pulling a report?

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I work with the nagios webapp with a rather large number of machines; so many in fact that when I pull up the report window the window times out when it does it's inital "today" query.  If I'm fast enough, I can sometimes get it to pull a different query by entering what I need under the "custom" period for a smaller slice of time.  Is there a way to stop this query from coming up initally so I can just enter what I need to query and then pull it without it automatically running?

Comment: sharing results of your issues will get you a better answer

Comment: @SivaPrasath I know what the issue is, it's that the query is pulling too much data initally.  The closest thing I have to an answer is to scrap the user interface all together and just send a query with something lilke curl or wget and get back a CSV result, so I don't have to worry about the dreaded three flashing dots.  Sharing that information won't help.

Comment: Basically there are no "results" there's just a query that times out.